# Multiple ggplots with magrittr tee operator

Tags: r, ggplot2, magrittr

I am trying to figure out why the tee operator, %T>%, does not work when I pass the data to a ggplot command.

This works fine

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

mtcars %T>%
  qplot(x = cyl, y = mpg, data = ., geom = "point") %>%
  qplot(x = mpg, y = cyl, data = ., geom = "point")
```

And this also works fine

```
mtcars %>%
  {ggplot() + geom_point(aes(cyl, mpg)) ; . } %>%
  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(mpg, cyl))
```

But when I use the tee operator, as below, it throws "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class protoenvironment".

```
mtcars %T>%
  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(cyl, mpg)) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(mpg, cyl))
```

Can anyone explain why this final piece of code does not work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either

```
mtcars %T>%
  {print(ggplot(.) + geom_point(aes(cyl, mpg)))} %>%
  {ggplot(.) + geom_point(aes(mpg, cyl))}
```

or abandon the `%T>%` operator and use an ordinary pipe with the "%>T%" operation made explicit as a new function as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27297298/1664978)

```
techo <- function(x){
    print(x)
    x
  }

mtcars %>%
  {techo( ggplot(.) + geom_point(aes(cyl, mpg)) )} %>%
  {ggplot(.) + geom_point(aes(mpg, cyl))}
```

As TFlick noted, the reason the %T>% operator doesn't work here is because of the precedence of operations: `%any%` is done before `+`.

Answer (score 7):

I think your problem has to do with order of operations. The `+` is stronger than the `%T>%` operator (according to the `?Syntax` help page). You need to pass in the data= parameter to `ggplot` before you add the `geom_point` otherwise things get messy. I think you want

```
mtcars %T>%
  {print(ggplot(.) + geom_point(aes(cyl, mpg)))} %>%
  {ggplot(.) + geom_point(aes(mpg, cyl))}
```

which uses the functional "short-hand" notation

Comment: You may need to wrap the first ggplot call with a print to get both calls to a graphics device.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a returned ggplot object is a list with $data field. This can be taken advantaged of. Personally I think the style is cleaner:)

```
ggpass=function(pp){
print(pp)
return(pp$data)
}
mtcars %>%
  {ggplot() + geom_point(aes(cyl, mpg))} %>% ggpass() %>%
  {ggplot() + geom_point(aes(mpg, cyl))}
```